# echo options for select box based on string

Tags: php

I have a string called `$number`.

If let's say it is set to `$number = "12";`

How can I automatically echo 12 options in a select box with the value as each number?

thanks

Comment: a loop, count til $number, echo the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an [basic php programming](http://howtostartprogramming.com/PHP/)

using only for loop or while :

```
<?php 
  $number = "12";
  $html = "<select>";
  for($inc = 0 *;$inc<$number;$inc++){
   $html .= "<option value=".$inc.">option ".$inc."</option>"; 
 }
 $html .= "</select>";
 echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: You have some typos and also this wont increment the values in option. Ive tweaked your code as new answer :)

Comment: @Asim corrected , ty

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for is to populate an select box and `echo` the option based on the int `$number`. I saw the previous answer but that would not work in your case, because you need to increment the value of each option. I tweaked the previous answer so it would work

```
<?php
    $html = "<select>";
    for ($number=0; $number<=12; $number++) {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$number.'">' .$number. '</option>';
    }
    $html .= "</select>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

You can add your `$number` value as in this example it is 12.

This will populate in HTML looking like this:

[image]

Hope this answer your question. Also recommend you to read this documentation: [PHP Library](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)